# How to check whether $f$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-continuity

Suppose that $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is a function satisfying $|f(x)-f(y)|\le |x-y|^\beta $.

If $\beta >0$ show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

**Attempt**:

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then choose $\delta =\epsilon^{\dfrac{1}{\beta}}$.
So whenever $|x-y|<\delta$

Then $|f(x)-f(y)|\le |x-y|^\beta<\delta^\beta=\epsilon$.

Is the method right  ?Please suggest required edits if required.

Comment: Looks correct to me. (Can you use \frac instead of \dfrac for the exponential of $\epsilon$?)